# What does JAX WS 2.0/2.1 compliant means?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I'm going to connect to a web service which has a WSDL which is said to be JAX WS 2.0/2.1 compliant. What does it mean? Will it have any impact on the way I connect to the web service? What certain measures do I need to make to be able to connect successfully to a JAX WS 2.0/2.1 web service? I am using JDK 1.5 and it says that JAX WS is only available on JDK 1.6. Currently, I'm planning to build the soap envelope manually and pass it as a body to HttpURLConnection. Am I doing it wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAX-WS 2.0/2.1 compliant just mean jax ws can generate a valid pojo model from a wsdl, if you plan to handle the low leve soap message generation yourself, you are not using the JAX-WS model

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If I'm not using the JAX-WS model, does it mean that I'm not complying to the web service? Is it required for me to use the JAX-WS model to be able to connect to a JAXWS compliant web service? Sorry, I don't have any background on JAXWS. I only know that it is an API that can be used for connecting or building web services.

Comment: It is not needed, but it makes life a hell alot easier if you do

Comment: Thanks again! Just to clarify: The compliance level is only needed if the client side is also going to use JAX-WS to generate their POJOs? If the client side is not using JAX-WS, then whether the server side is JAX WS 2.0 compliant or not, it doesn't matter?

Comment: In most cases to have a valid webservice is enough, but sometimes there are connection problems in most cases due to MTOM feature. If you want to create a simple soap services probably client apss have no problem

Comment: Ouch. If that's the case, how can I make the client side also JAX WS 2.0 compliant? Is using JAX WS the only way? Or are there sets of standards or rules that I can follow to make the client side JAX WS compliant without using JAX WS?

Comment: just make sure it is a valid SOAP (1.1 / 1.2) webservice, most likely you will have no problem. SOAP 1.1 is probably the saves road to victory

Answer (score 1):

You will not have any main difference in the way you connect the web service , because you just make a request to the web service. This compliance is more about the implementer of the web service.

and if you want to check why you need JDK 1.6 for Jax WS 2.0 :
[JAX-RPC Evolves into Simpler, More Powerful JAX-WS 2.0](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/30459/1954)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Then saying the web service is JAX WS compliant won't have any effect on the client side? If it won't have any effect on the client side, then why there's a need to mention that the server side is JAX WS 2.0 compliant? I don't know if a JAX WS web service follows a certain set of rules so I'm not sure if I need to make certain measures on the client side to be able to connect successfully on a JAX WS 2.0 compliant web service.

Comment: What IDE are you using ? which language ? Netbeans has so useful tools for JAX WS clients , even a rusty one for RPC

Comment: I'm using Eclipse and Java. However, we're on JDK 1.5 so I can't use JAX WS. While I think it is possible to download the required jars to use JAX WS, I won't make it through my deadline if I study it.  @.@ I've only managed to use JAXB so far.

Comment: oh alright. apart from my answer and this question , i strongly suggest netbeans over eclipse for java. some comparison on netbeanse page : http://netbeans.org/features/platform/compare.html